# how do I see if two values are not equal in APL?

Tags: apl

Writing an APL function- how do I check to see if two values are not equal? 
I tried like this:

```
 :If (rowValue ≠ columnValue)
```

but that gives me a LengthError.
Thank you!

Comment: By the way, you don't need to parenthesise the condition.

Comment: Worked, thank you!!

Comment: Are you the only APL programmer on StackOverflow? : )

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apl/topusers). You're welcome to join [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `≢` rather than `≠`.

`≢` ([full documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Not%20Match.htm)) checks if the the left argument is different from the right argument in any way (rank, shape or content). It returns a single scalar `0` (false) only if the arrays are identical, else `1` (true).

`≠` ([full documentation](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Not%20Equal.htm)) compares each atomic element in the left argument to the corresponding atomic element in the right argument. It pervades all structure, returning one Boolean per atomic element. If the arguments do not have compatible shapes, an error is signalled.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `≢`.

Note that many browser engines have a rendering bug which means that the Unicode character `≢` U+2262 "Not identical to" renders as "Identical to" `≡` followed by a slash `/` like `≢` . [This *is* a single character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2262/index.htm) (and displays correctly in all text editor that I have come across).
It should look like this: [image: <code>≢</code>]